# High Side, High Voltage Shunt Measurement with Differential ADC

Tags: adc, high-voltage, differential, isolation, shunt

I need to measure the high-side current out of an LED driver. The problem is that the output voltage can be as high as 250V. One solution would be to float an ADC and digital isolator just below supply voltage using a zener diode. However I'm not keen on the cost of the isolator or the power dissipation of the bias resistor.

Another solution might be to simply isolate the ADC ground from the LED driver ground, but I'm having difficulty finding any information on how to do this. There's this diagram [from Maxim](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/06/grounding-considerations---intermediate-analog-concepts.html)

[image]

and this one (top left) [from NI](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/06/grounding-considerations---intermediate-analog-concepts.html)

[image: NI Input Configurations]

but that's all I could find. Together, they suggest that this solution is at least possible, but the accompanying pages are short on details. The Maxim one references a non-existent bias resistor, and the NI one biases the inputs to ADC ground rather than Vref/2.

So my question is twofold. 1) Is this a viable solution? 2) If so, how would one implement it?

Comment: You could do it in hard mode like that, or you could use a purpose-made high-side current sense IC like Microchip's [HV7800](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/HV7800%20A062813.pdf)

Comment: @brhans Unfortunately I need something more accurate. Closer to 0.1% ideally. I also don't see any drift figures.

Comment: Perhaps something as this ... Common-Mode Voltage Range: ±275 V  ,  Maximum Gain Error: 0.02% inputs are protected from momentary common-mode – Maximum Gain Error Drift: 10 ppm/°C or differential overloads of up to 500 V. – Maximum Gain Nonlinearity: 0.001% FSR  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina149.pdf?ts=1633626261594&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA149  Perhaps also this https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1144&context=ese_papers

Comment: I found also this https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8479.pdf